# JS Persistence library that will PATCH only changed values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular, ngresource

I am evaluating JS persistence libraries. I'm on an Angular stack so ngResource and Restangular are options, but so are Breeze and Backbone's Models/collections and I'm open to others.

Is there a JS persistence library out there that will monitor changes to the model and do a `PATCH` of only the changed properties?

Example:

```
// Get a pretend user with a name, email, and some other stuff.
var currentUser = user.get(42)
// Change only the email address
currentUser.email = 'tractorDaddy@aol.com'
// Save changes
// The model could know that only one property has changed.
// The model could do a PATCH of a partial object, but I don't know a library that does.
currentUser.save()
```

This seems like it should be the default implementation but none of these libraries do it, that I could see.

Backbone's model decides whether to `POST` or `PUT` based on the newness of the model (determined by presence of id, as I recall). I think this is a nice move and could be extended to include `PATCH`.

I understand that Restangular and others have a `.patch()` method, but I believe in all cases you have to specify the object partial explicitly.

Is there a library that does this?

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: @jrhicks: I went with restangular. I don't think I'd make the same decision again. The value it provides doesn't outweigh having to think in terms of his abstraction. (eg: "Ok, I want to post to `api/users/7/preferences`, how do I write that in Restangular?) For objects that need a lean `PATCH` (because they'd be huge to do a `PUT` on), I do the diff myself. The difference between `POST` and `PUT` I also need to keep track of. The situation is not ideal. The Angular team is working on rich data models for 2.0 that look great: http://tinyurl.com/pa7rxf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no existing JS model/persistence layer that will track and `PATCH` only change values.

I have high hopes for AngularJS 2.0's data layer: http://tinyurl.com/pa7rxf8